# Segmentation fault in freeradius-utils package on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, samba, 22.04, bug-reporting

Running standard Ubuntu 22.04 using the official Docker image, I get a segfault when attempting to use `smbencrypt` from freeradius-utils:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu:22.04
# apt update && apt install -y freeradius-utils
# smbencrypt test
LM Hash                         NT Hash
--------------------------------        --------------------------------
Segmentation fault
```

gdb backtrace points to libfreeradius-radius.so:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fd5ba711dbe in fr_md4_calc () from /usr/lib/freeradius/libfreeradius-radius.so
#2  0x000055cbfd9ba213 in main ()
```

Is this a known bug? I can't find any information through Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a freeradius-server bug and it has to do with the update to OpenSSL 3.0.0 in Ubuntu 22. Reported [here](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/issues/4539). It's been fixed in the 3.0.x and 3.2.x branches, so I imagine it will be fixed in the Ubuntu package as soon as it's updated. In the meantime, you can [build freeradius-server from source](https://wiki.freeradius.org/building/Debian%20and%20Ubuntu#building-the-stable-release-v3-0_building-from-source) if you need it.